# Laravel : Update Database using Ajax. What's I should to do next?

Tags: ajax, database, laravel

I need the guidance of somebody to help me building the function Update Database when using AJAX. When I click the button Accept so an Ajax request will send to the server and server will execute UPDATE value of field *post_status*. At the start, field *post_status* has value is "pending", and after execute query UPDATE so the value will change to "accepted".
What's I should do next? Please help me.
Thank you so much for help.

- The database of the Posts table:

```
post_id user_id    title       content      DateTime      post_status
1          1      Title 1     Content 1       Time         pending
2          2      Title 2     Content 2       Time         pending
3          3      Title 3     Content 3       Time         pending
4          4      Title 4     Content 4       Time         pending
5          5      Title 5     Content 5       Time         pending
```

- The View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>Post ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Name User</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Datetime</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Accept</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($posts as $row)
            <tr id="{{ $row->post_id }}"> 
                <td>{{$row->post_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->user_id}}</td>
                <th>{{$row->users->name}}</th>
                <td>{{$row->post_title}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_content}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_datetime}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_status}}</td>      {{-- The status of post that I wanna change the value to "accepted"  --}}
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success accept-btn" data-postID="{{$row->post_id}}">Accept</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
```

- The code Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('.accept-btn').click(function(){
            var postId = $(this).attr('data-postID');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{route('posts.list_post_ajax')}}",      
                data: { postId: postId },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success :function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
            });

        })
    });
</script>
```

- The function list_post_ajax of Controller:

```
    public function list_post_ajax(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax()){
            $postId = $request->get('postId');
            return response()->json(['success'=>$postId]);   

            // What's I should do next?
            // Pls help me.
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it. This one will work following your code. Use `$myObject->save();` to save a new record or update a old one.

Change on view

```
<td id="td{{$row->post_id}}">{{$row->post_status}}</td>
```

On Controller

```
$postId = $request->get('postId');

$post = App\Post::find($postId);

$post->post_status= 'accepted';

$post->save();

return response()->json(['success'=>$postId,'message'=>'accepted']);
```

On JS

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('posts.list_post_ajax')}}",      
            data: { postId: postId },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success :function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                 $('td'+postId).html(response.message);
            },
        });
```

Edit: I update my answer on Controller. You should take a look [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) Documentation

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna execute Query UPDATE table posts SET status = "accepted" on function list_post_ajax of Controller. It's made to change the value of **post_status ** is "accepted". I don't know code query building UPDATE?
`
public function list_post_ajax(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax()){
            $postId = $request->get('postId');
            return response()->json(['success'=>$postId,'message'=>'accepted']);

            // What's I should to do next?
            // Pls help me.
        }
        
        
    }
`

Comment: I have fixed that problem